# Is there a way to increase Cpickle limit when doing python2 multirpocessing without changing the code to python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, multiprocessing, pickle

As the title says, is there a way to increase the limit of Cpickle module in python2 multiprocessing?

There is a program I want to use which is written in python2.7 and it keeps giving me errors due to Cpickle size limit of 2Gib. As I'm aware of the fact that python3 has a better pickle tool, I can't upgrade the code to python3 cause the program uses multiprocessing inside a .so module written in Cython. I don't have the Cython file which was used to make the .so therefore I can't change it either.
Is there a way I can change the code in multiprocessing and Cpickle module to increase the size of Cpickle?

Comment: Is this a 32 bit .so?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to tell cause I'm new to this.. it says it's generated by Cython 0.23.3

Comment: `readelf -a my.so | grep Class` would say for instance, ELF64.

Comment: I read about dill and it seems to be a similar module to pickle but I can't change the code to use dill cause I can't fix the SO file. 
In So file, I can tell it uses Process,Queue,JoinableQueue so I can't touch it. 
The only thing I can do is to change some codes in python multiprocessing package that interacts with Process, Queue, JoinableQueue to increase pickle limits.

Comment: that was meant for a seperate post, too many tabs.

Comment: when I do readelf -a my.so | grep Class, it says ELF64